# Maven Deploy Plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, heap-memory, maven-deploy-plugin

I have been migrating our maven build server over from Maven 2 to Maven 3. I am setting up maven to deploy a new java application to a remote server using scp. However, I get the following messages when I run "mvn install".

```
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Reactor Build Order:
    [INFO]
    [INFO] FooCorp Parent Project
    [INFO] FooCorp Daemons
    [INFO] FooCorp Transport Objects and Interfaces
    [INFO] FooCorp Web Client
    [INFO] FooCorp Web Application
    [INFO]
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building FooCorp Parent Project S88-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3:install (default-install) @ Foo ---
    [INFO] Installing /home/ubuntu/FooCorp/pom.xml to /home/ubuntu/mvn_local_repo/com/Foo/Foo/S88-SNAPSHOT/Foo-S88-SNAPSHOT.pom
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) @ Foo ---
    Downloading: scp://mvn.FooCorp.com/var/www/maven2/com/Foo/Foo/S88-
SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.jcraft.jsch.IdentityFile.decrypt_rsa(IdentityFile.java:648)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.IdentityFile.decrypt(IdentityFile.java:553)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.IdentityFile.setPassphrase(IdentityFile.java:435)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.addIdentity(JSch.java:225)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.addIdentity(JSch.java:207)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.addIdentity(JSch.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.ssh.jsch.AbstractJschWagon.openConnectionInternal(AbstractJschWagon.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.openConnection(AbstractWagon.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.connect(AbstractWagon.java:217)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.connectWagon(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:345)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.pollWagon(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:385)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:571)
    at org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is some information about the system I am using.

```
:> echo $MAVEN_OPTS
-Xmx2000m -Xms256m
:> mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.0.5
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_65, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-36-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Running on Ubuntu 14.04 with 4GB total memory.

I get the same error message every time I run `mvn install`. The file that is being downloaded in the last command before the java heap space exception ...
`Downloading: scp://mvn.FooCorp.com/var/www/maven2/com/Foo/Foo/S88-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml`
... Does exist on the remote server (I  have access to it so I checked). Maven seems to have plenty of memory according the the MAVEN_OPTS. Also, I have watched the system memory using the top command and it barely ever uses more than 1.5GB of memory. I have looked at many other solutions to problems such as this and they all involve giving Maven more memory, but I think 2GB should cover whatever maven needs (Might I be wrong). Not sure if this helps, but I am able to run "mvn install" and it works perfectly. The only problem is the maven deploy command.

The wagon plugin is configured in my POM.xml like so

```
<extensions>
    <extension>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </extension>
</extensions>
```

And the maven-deploy-plugin configuration is configured in the POM like this...

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-Xmx3000m</argLine>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I have been having a hard time with this, not sure what else to try. Any possible solutions or general advice would be greatly appreciated.

I can add more information if necessary.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: can you take heap dump while it is deploying

Comment: Tried adding the following lines to my MAVEN_OPTS:
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
And added that option to my surefire plugin
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <argLine>-Xmx3000m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError</argLine>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
but couldn't get maven to do a heap dump.

Comment: can you observe heapdump or it is faster process ? by manually doin igt

Comment: I was able to get a heap dump by manually setting the heap dump path. Opened it with the eclipse memory analyzer tool. Not sure what I am looking for though.

Comment: The maven-deploy-plugin does not has an configuration item `<argLine>..</argLine>`. The question is why are you trying to use maven-deploy-plugin to deploy to transfer to remote app server. maven-deploy-plugin is intended to deploy artifacts to a repository. If you like to deploy i would suggest to use [cargo-maven2-plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin) instead.

Comment: I am using the maven-deploy-plugin to deploy a pom and a war to the repository mvn.FooCorp.com/var/www/maven2/com/Foo/Foo/S88-
SNAPSHOT/ using scp. Thanks for the tip about the argLine tag. Should have read the docs about that one.

Comment: Why don't you use a usual repository manager which handles it via http instead of scp ? Furthermore which maven-wagon version do you use? How have you setup the wagon?

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the heap size.
PFB links for reference.Hope this may help you.

http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/08/increase-heap-size-maven-ant.html

http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/09/javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space.html

:> echo $MAVEN_OPTS
-Xmx2000m **-Xms256m**

Try increasing the size of highlighted bold to -Xms512m and try once again

Comment: I attempted this solution, but I got the same results as described in my original post. Thank you for the suggestion though!